# How do I add syntax highlighting support for TypeScript string interpolation in an Emacs major mode?

Tags: typescript, emacs, major-mode

I'm trying to write a custom major mode for TypeScript in Emacs. I would like for my major mode to highlight the following code correctly:

```
const myString = `The meaning of life is ${40 + 2}`;
```

Inside of the back ticks, `${40 + 2}` should be highlighted as *not* a string, but a normal TypeScript expression; everything else should be recognized as a string. What's the right way to handle this case? Does the answer have something to do with `font-lock` or the syntax table for my major mode? I would appreciate any advice or pointers to relevant documentation.

Comment: Not an expert in syntax tables, but I would start by looking at `syntax-propertize-function` and `syntax-propertize-extend-region-functions`